# How to hide dash to dock in app grid?

Tags: gnome, dash-to-dock

I am using Ubuntu 21.10 with Gnome 40.5. I was looking for a way to hide the dash while viewing the app grid accessed through the show applications button, but was unable to find an extension or setting to do so.

[image]

As seen in the image above, the dash is visible at the bottom in the app grid. Since my favourites are shown in the app grid, having the dash in this view is redundant which is why I would like to remove it.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the dash with the following command:

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.dash.hide();'
```

You will need to add this command to your autostart programs to have it in effect after each login.

Alternatively, the Gnome Shell extension [Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) by JustPerfection includes within the many settings an option to hide the Dash.

Hiding the dash in the overview will also hide the Ubuntu dock on the desktop. To still have a dock, your only option will be to use a third third party dock, e.g. Plank. What you presicely want is not possible (at least without coding or lacking an extension for that), and you have to live with the Dock also appearing in the overview.

Comment: I only need it to be hidden while viewing the app grid, not always

Comment: I indeed was assuming it would also disable the Dock, which is drawn on the desktop with an extension, but I cannot test myself. Hiding in the application overview without hiding on the desktop is not possible (at least, no extension does that. I will include a workaround.

Comment: I tried Plank and Docky, neither has the option

Comment: What option are you looking for? These are third party docks that run separately from Gnome Shell. To hide the dock from Gnome Shell, you need an extension. To still have a dock, you need a third party dock. Otherwise what you want is not possible, and you have to live with the Dock also appearing in the overview. I clarified the answer in that respect.